# Dart range operator

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been looking at Dart and I was wondering if it has a range operator like the one Kotlin has 
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html
or anything similar to that.

Answer (score 17):

You could use [List.generate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/List.generate.html), like this:

```
var list = List.generate(4, (i) => i);
print(list); // prints [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Or

```
List _range(int from, int to) => List.generate(to - from + 1, (i) => i + from);
print(_range(3, 6)); // prints [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: This is slow and takes a ton of memory, because it generates a whole list :/

Answer (score 4):

There is no such operator in Dart at the current time.

Comment: Is there a way to propose they add it?

Answer (score 4):

For quite some time (since September 2014), `Iterable.generate(n)` has been available which iterate integers from `0` to `n-1`. Currently that seems to be the closed you can get to a `range()` like function.

See the discussion in this [issue 7775](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/7775#issuecomment-108346855)

Usage example:

```
Iterable.generate(5).forEach((i) => print(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such operator in Dart at the current time.

but try these codes

1.

```
List<int> range(int from, int from)=>List.generate(10,(i)=>i);
```

2. 

```
Iterable<int> range(int from,int to,[int stepSize=1]) sync*{
 for(int i = from;i<to;i+=stepSize){
   yield i;
  }
}
```

3. 

```
  Iterable<int> to(int end, [int stepSize = 1]) sync* {
    if (this <= end) {
      for (var i = this; i < end; i += stepSize) yield i;
    } else {
      for (var i = this; i > end; i -= stepSize) yield i;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [range_type](https://pub.dev/packages/range_type) dart package for using ranges.

```dart
import 'package:range_type/predefined_ranges.dart';

void main() {
  final july = DateTimeRange.parse('[2022-07-01, 2022-08-01)');

  final scheduleDate1 = DateTime(2022, 07, 02);
  final scheduleDate2 = DateTime(2022, 08, 07);

  final workingDays = DateTimeRange.parse('[2022-07-20, 2022-08-15)');

  print('Is scheduleDate1 in July? ${july.containsElement(scheduleDate1)}');
  print('Is scheduleDate2 in July? ${july.containsElement(scheduleDate2)}');
  print('Is workingDays overlaps? ${july.overlap(workingDays)}');
  print('workingDays intersection: ${july.intersection(workingDays)}');
  print('workingDays union: ${july.union(workingDays)}');
  print('july difference workingDays: ${july.difference(workingDays)}');
}
```